# ajax request without data not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete a photo using ajax and when the photo is deleted show default image instantly, so far I am done with php side but the ajax part isn't working. How can I make an ajax request without data type?

```
function delete_image()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "target.php?page=delete",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {  
            var $divs = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");
              $("#phd").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".suc_pic").fadeIn('slow').empty().append($divs.find("#msg"));//the default picture fades in once the photo is deleted.

           }
    });


}
```

Comment: That should work. In what way do you think it isn't?

Comment: @KevinB when i click on the delete button nothing is happening, I guess it isn't sending the request to php page.

Comment: Debug further. How far into that event handler is it getting? if it never gets to the success callback, does it get to the error callback?

Comment: Don't you need the image id to delete?

Comment: Do a `console.dir(response)` in your `success` function and post us the result from the console.

Comment: @doitmyway This is what I get...A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element....... @@wilmer I am doing all that on the php yeah using the logged in user session.

Comment: Do what it says - set the charset to UTF-8 and try again. Also, as Wilmer pointed out, you need to pass an id of the image you want to delete.

Comment: @doitmyway how I do so, I have no idea? I don't need id cos I am using the logged in user session so there will only be one profile picture per user.

Comment: To set the charset to UTF-8, either do so in the text editor of your choice, or add this to the `<head>` section in your HTML markup: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Oh okay but that didn't change anything at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try move *"page= delete"* in data secction:

```
function delete_image()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "target.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {  
                var $divs = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");
                  $("#phd").fadeOut('slow');
                $(".suc_pic").fadeIn('slow').empty().append($divs.find("#msg"));//the default picture fades in once the photo is deleted.

            },
            data: {page='delete'}
        });

    }
```